# How to disable individual tests in Flutter

Tags: flutter, unit-testing

We have a Flutter app that connects to some backend services. For debugging, it's very hand to have some tests around that can be run manually. However, in our build pipeline we want those tests to be disabled, so our builds don't fail if the backend services are not available.

So effectively, we want to have the tests in the project, but don't want them to be executed unless we specifically enable them.

From Java, I am used to having something like a `@Disabled` annotation that can be put above test classes and individual tests. Is there something like that in Flutter? I already tried `@Skip`, but the IDE told me that it is only for libraries, and it didn't have any effect.

Currently, we use this workaround:

```
void main() {
  const disabled = true; //These tests are only for manual use

  if (!disabled) {
    initializeGetItContext();

    test("Some Test", () async {
      //Test Logic
    });

    test("Some Other Test", () async {
      //Test Logic
    });
  }
}
```

...however, that causes the warning "dead code" (and rightly so). So this is not an ideal solution. Is there a better way to do that? Or is that not possible (yet) in Flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the flag `skip: true`.

```
void main() {
  const disabled = true; //These tests are only for manual use

  initializeGetItContext();

  test("Some Test", () async {
    //Test Logic
  }, skip: disabled);

  test("Some Other Test", () async {
    //Test Logic
  }, skip: disabled);
}
```

Comment: That works. I suppose there's no way to exclude the `initializeGetItContext();` without putting it into each test though, is there?